# assigning variable outside main: data definition has no type or storage class

Tags: c, memory, malloc, language-design

Why this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *mem;
*mem = 3;
int main(){
    int *mem2 = malloc(4*4);
    mem=mem2;
    for(int i =0; i<4 ; i++)
        mem[i]=i;

    printf("%i\n",mem[2]);
}
```

Is giving this warnings:

```
a.c:5:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 *mem = 3;
 ^
a.c:5:2: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘mem’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 *mem = 3;
  ^~~
a.c:5:8: warning: initialization of ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 *mem = 3;
```

1. mem has no type or storage, but it should be of type (int*)
2. type defaults to int, but the mem already has type

Why is the problem it is outside main? I have no function or logic, only *simple* assignment, then why is it problem? Having it assembled, the `mem` resides in text segment, not data segment (strange), otherwise it is normally accessed via rip-relative mode (e.q `mov %rax, mem(%rip)`), so no problem here.

```
    .text
    .globl  mem
    .data
    .align 8
    .type   mem, @object
    .size   mem, 8
mem:
    .quad   3
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%i\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    ...
```

Comment: you cannot have `*mem = 3;` out of a function. Note even you have that in a function without initializing *mem* to a valid address you cannot do `*mem = 3;` else the behavior is undefined. Also doing `malloc(4*4);` you suppose the size of an `int` is 4, better to do `malloc(4*sizeof(int));` or `malloc(4*sizeof(*mem2));` to let the compiler doing the job in a secure way

Comment: It's not a question of assembly-language, the problem is C language design and how code outside of functions is parsed / how the compiler is trying to make any sense of it.  I fixed the tags on the question to reflect the real reason for the error messages. 
 Also, no, `mem` isn't going to be in the text segment, that's not plausible because it's not `const`.

Comment: @PeterCordes you can look at the edit. It is either in .text or .rodata (mem is in scope of .text, but inside, it is define as `.section .rodata`), However, it is not definitely in data segment

Comment: If it is not in main, and not called by main, when do you expect that assignment to run?

Comment: @stark as from above comment, I am not quite sure. Is define "under" `.text` segment, but in the label defintion, there is `.section .rodate`. I do not know how long is the scope of a segment/section, so I do not know after what does it belong

Comment: It doesn't matter what section its in.  Execution starts at main() and proceeds from there.  If a statement can't be reached, then it is not executed.

Comment: @stark. So can you please tell me, what is the scope of segments? How can a variable defined by label in a particular segment (defined before that label), declare its own segment by `.section` directive? How long does this "new" segment live (what is its scope)?

Comment: Segments don't appear and disappear.  The text segment is created at compile time and exists as long as your program exists.  The problem isn't creating the variable.  The problem is the lonely assignment statement.

Comment: @stark still the same question. WHat is the scope of segmet? Is it .text? Is it .rodata? Why is there `.section` directive, when the label(variable) *already* has a section `.text`?

Comment: @milanHrabos: the last section directive *before* `mem:` is `.data`.  As expected, your mutable global is in the .data section which will be linked into a read+write segment.  Note that a few commonly-used sections have shorthand directives that don't start with `.section`.  After mem, the compiler switches to another section for the next global thing, which is a string literal in `.rodata`.  Despite the indenting and proximity, notice that `.section .rodata` is *after* `mem: .quad`, so it's unrelated. (Also, `mem` would be in `.bss`, probably defined with `.comm`, if you left it zero-inited.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside any function you may use only declarations. So the compiler tries to interpret this statement

```
*mem = 3;
```

as a declaration where a type specifier is absent.

```
a.c:5:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 *mem = 3;
 ^
```

To support the backward compatibility with the old C Standard the compiler by default uses the type specifier `int`.

Pay attention to that if you will place this code snippet

```
int *mem;
*mem = 3;
```

inside a function nevertheless it will have undefined behavior because the pointer `mem` does not point to a valid object of the type int.

Answer (score 3):

The following is illegal.  Even it it wasn't, it would be undefined behavior.

```
int *mem;
*mem = 3;
int main(){
}
```

You change it to something like the following, if you must:

```
int num = 3;
int *mem = &num;
int main(){
}
```

As pointed out by @bruno, the following may work as expected, but isn't portable:

```
int *mem2 = malloc(4*4);
```

For portability, change it to one of the following:

```
int *mem2 = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
int *mem2 = malloc(4 * sizeof(*mem2));
```

The second option is considered better as it won't result in a runtime error if the type of `mem2` is changed, to `double` for example.

Comment: I encourage you to also speak about `malloc(4*4);` to remove the supposition about `int` size

Comment: @bruno Didn't even read that part of the code.  Good suggestion.